# Finding probability that there are more than 10 but less than or equal to 12 customers arriving between 10 am and 11:30 am

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> The number of customers arriving at a grocery store is a Poisson random variable with on average 10 customers arriving per hour. Let $X$ be the number of customers arriving from 10 am to 11:30a m. What is the probability that there are more than 10 but less than or equal to 12 customers arriving between 10 am and 11:30 am ($P(10 < X \le 12)$)?

Do I use the Poisson distribution formula using mean=10 or mean=15 because it is for 1.5 hrs?

And then do I just do $P(10 < X \le 12) = P(X=11) + P(X=12)$ where for $P(X=11)$, $\lambda=15$ and $X=11$, and for $P(X=12)$, $\lambda$ is $15$ and $X=12$.

Because so far I am getting 0.1491 but unsure of which mean to use.

Comment: You did the right things: $\lambda=15$ and $P(10<X\leq 12)=P(X=11)+P(X=12)$ where $X\sim\mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda=15)$.

Comment: @drhab How do you type "Poisson" like that in LaTeX?

Comment: @EkeshKumar \mathsf{Poisson} between dollar signs.

Comment: @EkeshKumar - (this works at least for me, in windows / chrome) if you right-click on the math expression, it brings up a menu where one option is "Show Math As" > "TeX commands".  I have learned much this way.  :)